# React Native placeholder icon

Tags: javascript, react-native, placeholder, string-concatenation

I have a problem with putting an icon inside placeholder of DatePicker in React Native. In fact, I have a problem to put some text ('Search by date') next to that icon. I tried with ES6 template strings but it doesn't work, or I am missing something...
Here is the code:

```
 <View style={styles.searchDateView}>
      <DatePicker
        defaultDate={this.state.chosenDate}
        minimumDate={new Date(1970, 1, 1)}
        maximumDate={new Date(2050, 12, 31)}
        placeHolderText={<FontAwesome5 name="calendar-alt" size={20} />}
        textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }}
        placeHolderTextStyle={styles.placeHolderTextStyle}
        onDateChange={date => this.onDateChange(date)
      />
    </View>
```

Inside "placeHolderText" I have an icon, and next to it, I want to put text "Search by date".
This way, the icon is showing, but when I try to add text as well (using template strings), it doesn't show the icon, just text, and something like [object, Object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to S.O.! :-)

Is that specific icon mandatory?
Should something like this be feasible?

```
    ...
    placeHolderText={<Text>&#128197; Search by date</Text>}
    ...
```

This *should* work (untested...)

P.S.: There are many other unicode calendar icons out there... i.e.: https://www.alt-codes.net/calendar-symbols.

Comment: MarcoS, thank you, I am happy to be here! Yes, I have to use these fontAwesome icons, but I will keep in mind those that you sent me. And your solution works perfectly! I put <FontAwesome5 name="calendar-alt" size={20} /> inside <Text> tag, together with my text. Thank you very much! I forgot on <Text> tags totally...